# Does my code have to be written in php to intefrate WordPress

Tags: php, django, wordpress

Say for instance i have a web application that uses Django as a framework, is there going to be a problem when integrating WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

Depends by what you mean by integration. If you mean that some urls need to be  handled by Django and others by wordpress - then yes, it is possible you should not have to rewrite everything in PHP.

These links will be helpful as a starting point.

[How i can integrate my wordpress and django website?](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/how-i-can-integrate-my-wordpress-and-django-website/13855)

[How can I integrate a wordpress front-end on top of my existing Django web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195982/how-can-i-integrate-a-wordpress-front-end-on-top-of-my-existing-django-web-appli)

[Django Wordpress API](https://django-wordpress-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html)

[Simple django wordpress integration with Django WordPress API library](https://swapps.com/blog/simple-django-wordpress-integration-with-django-wordpress-api-library/)

[Integrating Django and WordPress can be simple](https://av.tib.eu/media/32838)

Comment: Thanks. I meant integrating a blog from WordPress into a existing website that using Django.

Comment: yes, the above links should help get you started to do that